# create new div onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to create new empty div onClick every time not once, is it right way to do this in react, I just doubt if it is correct to do this in react

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const parentRef = useRef();

  const createNewDiv = () => {
    parentRef.current.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div onClick={createNewDiv} ref={parentRef}>
        clickHere
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you have to bind divs to some array and then use `.map`. This would be a correct way to involve React Reconciliation mechanism

Comment: @Rostyslav thanks, can u show me on example please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use react **createElement** method instead of using **appendChild** directly.
Add new element in array and then display this array in the JSX.

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const parentRef = useRef();

  const [elements, setelements] = useState([]);

  const createNewDiv = () => {
   // parentRef.current.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));

    const newElement = React.createElement('div', {key: 'ele'+ new Date().getTime()}, `Hello`,);
    
    setelements(elements => [...elements,newElement]);

  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <div onClick={createNewDiv} ref={parentRef}>
        clickHere
      </div>
      {
        elements
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-oteyzm).